# How to use Accessors in Django, in which django-tables2 is connected, to display links to pages with data about each field in the table?

Tags: django, django-tables2

It is necessary in Django, in which django-tables2 is connected, to output a field with a link to a page with data about this field by `get_absolute_url()`.

To do this, I need to use `Accessors`, but how???

```
class GostTable(tables.Table):
     # get_absolute_url() I need on field 'name'!

    class Meta:
        model = Gost
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html" 
        fields = ('name', 'short_name')
```

I haven't any ideas about using `Accessors`...

Comment: Info on Accessors:
https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#using-accessors